# Add option to handle the review of an answer by flagging the question

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I am reviewing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42969036/2754507).

The problem there is in the question: it's just a simple typo and not likely to be helpful to others. We have a flag option for that and I used it.

However, to do that I had to open the question in another page. Now, my review cannot be marked as "Done" and I have to skip.

While that's not critical, I'd prefer to mark the review as "Done" since I've handled it by flagging the question.

To be more clear, I don't want to flag the post that I am reviewing, which is an answer. Rather, I want to flag the qestion that originated such answer, and I'd like to do it within the review

Comment: You should have flag both. It is not because a question is bad that the answer is not bad as well.

Comment: @Mistalis but in this case the answer wasn't bad. Or, if it was, its only badness was being the answer of a bad question, and there is not such closing reason...